# Rows highlight in an ADF table

Tags: row, oracle-adf

Can anybody please tell that how may I give color to the rows in an ADF table?

Four different colors and the sequenced be repeated in the table for the successive rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
        //define style class in skins file 
            .style1 { background-color:green; }
            .style2 { background-color:red;}
            .style3 { background-color:yellow; }
            .style4 { background-color:blue;}

    public long getCountRows(){
   ViewObjectImpl vo = getTourHeaderEOView_hdr();
   return vo.getEstimatedRowCount();
}
```

Comment: getcountrows method in  impl class

Comment: both answers are attached. By mistake i posted answer which was incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

```
private String styleForCell; //class variable

public String getStyleForCell() {


    OperationBinding ob2 = (OperationBinding)getBindings().get("getCountRows");
    int row = (Integer)ob2.execute();

    for(int i = 1;i <= row;i=i+4) {
       return "style1";
    }
    for(int i = 2;i <= row;i=i+4) {
       return "style2";
    }
    for(int i = 3;i <= row;i=i+4) {
       return "style3";
    }
    for(int i = 4;i <= row;i=i+4) {
       return "style4";
    }

    return null;
}
public void setStyleForCell(String aStyleForCell)
{
    this.styleForCell = aStyleForCell;
}
```

//now call this method through front end page from table with styleclass property(styleclass = "#{backinbean.styleforcell}"